# regex with XSLT and string modification

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, nlp

i'm progrossing in XSLT (slowly) and i have a task to do with strings ans regexp. Here is a sample of my xml file :

```
<items>
<item type="forme" pos="434"><f>le</f><c>D</c><l>le</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>sg</a><a>masc</a><a>DEP(436)</a><a>DEP(436)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>0</a><a>H</a><a>91.10469213033109</a><a>88.35438807575431</a><a>U</a><a>U_ml</a><a>ml</a><a>384.0760000000003</a><a>253.98099999999957</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>mlh2</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>included</a><a>hHL2</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>mHL2</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>mHL2</a><a>60.786288</a><a>61.170364</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:I)_(GR:I)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:I)_(PER:I)_(GR:I)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="435"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="436"><f>cours</f><c>N</c><l>cours</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>sg</a><a>masc</a><a>OBJ(432)</a><a>OBJ(432)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>S</a><a>S</a><a>-</a><a>89.13140170852544</a><a>93.87310688497651</a><a>U</a><a>U_hh</a><a>hh</a><a>228.2860000000042</a><a>270.4284999999977</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>mlh2</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>included</a><a>hHL2</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>mHL2</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>mHL2</a><a>61.170364</a><a>61.39865</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:L)_(GR:L)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:L)_(PER:I)_(GR:L)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="437"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="438"><f>Jean</f><c>N</c><l>Jean</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>sg</a><a>masc</a><a>DEP(436)</a><a>DEP(436)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>0</a><a>-</a><a>89.66516939765438</a><a>92.41608461220896</a><a>U</a><a>U_hl</a><a>hl</a><a>267.63799999999804</a><a>258.09050000000155</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>mlh2</a><a>B</a><a>B_hhl2</a><a>lone_hhl2</a><a>lone</a><a>hhl2</a><a>B</a><a>B_hhl2</a><a>B_strong_hhl2</a><a>strong</a><a>hhl2</a><a>B</a><a>B_strong</a><a>B_strong_hhl2</a><a>strong</a><a>hhl2</a><a>61.39865</a><a>61.666288</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:B)_(GR:B)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:B)_(PER:I)_(GR:B)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="439"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="440"><f>Jaurès</f><c>N</c><l>Jaurès</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>sg</a><a>masc</a><a>DEP(438)</a><a>DEP(438)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>L</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>S</a><a>0</a><a>-</a><a>89.91638709330856</a><a>89.01649305547852</a><a>U</a><a>U_lh</a><a>lh</a><a>260.0000000000051</a><a>213.81899999999732</a><a>$L1</a><a>0.126722999999998</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>mlh2</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>lone</a><a>hhl2</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>hhl2</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>hhl2</a><a>61.666288</a><a>62.086288</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:L)_(PAQ:L)_(GR:L)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:L)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:L)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:L)_(PER:L)_(GR:L)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="441"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="442"><f>#</f><c>DELIM</c><l>§</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="443"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="444"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="445"><f>si</f><c>CS</c><l>si</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>ROOT</a><a>ROOT</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>B</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>_</a><a>-</a><a>86.92136531453266</a><a>88.13351137193554</a><a>U</a><a>U_ml</a><a>ml</a><a>149.99999999999858</a><a>260.0000000000016</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>B</a><a>B_lh</a><a>lh</a><a>B</a><a>B_ml</a><a>lone_ml</a><a>lone</a><a>ml</a><a>B</a><a>B_ml</a><a>B_strong_ml</a><a>strong</a><a>ml</a><a>B</a><a>B_strong</a><a>B_strong_ml</a><a>strong</a><a>ml</a><a>62.213011</a><a>62.363011</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:B)_(PAQ:B)_(GR:B)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:B)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:B)</a><a>(PON:B)_(PAQ:B)_(PER:B)_(GR:B)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="446"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="447"><f>je</f><c>Cl</c><l>je</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>1</a><a>sg</a><a>-</a><a>SUB(451)</a><a>SUB(451)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>0</a><a>-</a><a>88.97374267270202</a><a>87.07924198196244</a><a>U</a><a>U_llm2</a><a>llm2</a><a>189.99999999999773</a><a>193.33333333333277</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>lh</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>lone</a><a>ml</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>ml</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>ml</a><a>62.363011</a><a>62.553011</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:I)_(GR:I)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:I)_(PAQ:I)_(PER:I)_(GR:I)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="448"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="449"><f>me</f><c>Cl</c><l>me</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>1</a><a>sg</a><a>-</a><a>DEP(451)</a><a>DEP(451)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>S</a><a>S</a><a>-</a><a>89.08184154908382</a><a>86.76348864710289</a><a>U</a><a>U_ll</a><a>ll</a><a>330.0000000000054</a><a>192.499999999999</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>lh</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>lone</a><a>ml</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>ml</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>ml</a><a>62.553011</a><a>62.883011</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:L)_(GR:L)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:I)_(PAQ:L)_(PER:I)_(GR:L)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="450"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
...
</items>
```

In fact I just have to concatenate all f nodes (words) to create sentences from item nodes When the f node = RETURN, i have to add carriage return. I can manage it. I did it. Here is my output.

```
Euh bon pour aller du CRDT à la gare euh de Grenoble je euh ben je sors déjà du CRDT. 
Je remonte euh l'avenue Général Champon. 
Je traverse euh face à la euh MDE. 
Et je euh je continue je continue jusqu'à une place qui est face à la grande poste. où il y a la euh Chambre de Commerce et d'Industrie. 
Et euh je reprends je crois le & non c'est pas le boulevard Gambetta. je ne sais pas lequel c'est euh. c'est l'autre. 
Et euh donc je vais jusqu'au & jusqu'à la place Victor Hugo. 
Et là je me retrouve euh en effet euh s~ près des rails du tram. 
Et euh et ces rails du tram eh ben je vais je vais les longer. 
Je vais traverser euh le boulevard Gambetta. 
Ça cette fois c'est le boulevard Gambetta. 
Ensuite euh je vais euh prendre je crois que c'est l'avenue Alsace-Lorraine. que je vais remonter remonter. 
Je vais traverser le cours Jean Jaurès. si je me souviens bien. 
Et je vais euh je vais toujours continuer cette avenue Alsace-Lorraine. 
Et euh et ben voilà j'arrive au niveau de la grande place de la gare où il y a tous les trams tous les bus. non pas tous les bus. 
Ils sont pas de ce côté-là. 
Et voilà. 
Et je suis arrivée sur la gare. 
Alors là tu vois donc tu continues tout droit tout droit. 
Tu traverses tout. 
Tu arrives à un rond-point. 
Au rond-point c'est tout droit direction Saint-Jean-de-Maurienne. 
Euh donc tou~ tou~ toujours Saint-Jean-de-Maurienne. 
Tu passes un autre rond-point. 
Donc toujours tout droit. 
Après tu montes une grande grande ligne droite. 
Tu passes devant la piscine. 
Euh il y a un stade aussi à côté. 
Et tu arrives à un rond-point. donc là tu rentres dans le centre-ville.
```

There are some words cutted in 2 by . It's the frontiere between two sentences. Is it possible to put the first letter of my second word in uppercase ? with regex and capture group or other ? I'm ttying to create a template but i don'tknow if it's recursive or not

```
Exemple : 
Jaurès. si = Jaurès. Si
```

Is it possible with my code or in XLST ? or do i have to change my way ? I know in Perl it's possible but i don't know about XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
       
      <xsl:for-each-group select="//item" group-ending-with="item[contains(f/text(),'RETURN')]">
          <xsl:variable name="phrase">
              <xsl:for-each select="current-group()//f">
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:variable name="phrase_norm" select="replace(replace(translate(string-join($phrase), '#£§§', ''), '(\W+)\s\s+RETURN', '. '), '\s\s+', '. ')"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(upper-case(substring($phrase_norm,1,1)), substring($phrase_norm, 2), ' '[not(last())])"/>
          <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
      
    </xsl:template>
    
   <xsl:template name="upper">
       <xsl:param name="text"></xsl:param>
       
       <xsl:analyze-string select="$text" regex="\W+\.\s(\W+)">
           <xsl:matching-substring>
               <xsl:for-each select="regex-group(1)">
                   <xsl:value-of select="replace($text, regex-group(1), (concat(upper-case(substring(regex-group(1),1,1)), substring(regex-group(1), 2)), ' '[not(last())]))"/>
               </xsl:for-each>                    
           </xsl:matching-substring>
       </xsl:analyze-string>
       
   </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
EDIT : the frist replace '(\W+)\s\s+RETURN', '. ' give my 2 spaces between, not the '. '.
```

Comment: Where in your sample input can we see a case where such a word is "cut in two" by a period and need to be capitalized?

Comment: i've updated the output : Jaurès. si, Gambetta. je

Comment: Please cut your samples to the minimal and essential to demonstrate the issue. If you tell us your code doesn't process `Jaurès. si` as desired but your more than 30 input items do not even contain the data we can't tell where your code fails.

Comment: There's no item that contains Jaurès in your input XML. It's impossible to debug for us.

Comment: Because the file is too big. I'm gonna update with only this part

Comment: Please take your time to prepare minimal and representative input sample to demonstrate one issue. If you show us grouping code `group-ending-with="item[contains(f/text(),'RETURN')]"` and the input data has no `item` with an `f` element and the value `RETURN` I don't know what you expect to achieve with that. Even all those wide screen wide `item` elements in the input with lots of child elements the code doesn't even process (your seem to be looking only for the `f` child) make it hard for us to grasp where the problem is.

Comment: the input file is to big even for one element with RETURN. Look at this sample. There are less than 10 words.